# Changing the language of the form

Tags: javascript, forms

I have a form with the default language set to English. At the top of the page I have links to 4 different languages (English, French, Italian, German) and what I want to do is once the user clicks one of the languages it changes the text of the input labels in the form to that specific language. I have stored the languages inside 4 separate text files but there is something not working in my JavaScript. I personally think it's a syntax error or maybe a small coding error I just don't notice.

HTML

```
<header>
        <ul id="languageChoice">
            <li class="rbord"><a name="deutsche" id="deutsche">Deutsche</a></li> 
            <li class="rbord"><a name="italiano" id="italiano">Italiano</a></li>
            <li class="rbord"><a name="Francais" id="francais">Francais</a></li>
            <li class="rbord"><a name="English" id="english">English</a></li>
        </ul>
    </header>
    <form method="GET" action="#" id="add1">
        <table>
            <tr><td class = "field"><label for="firstName">First Name:</label></td><td><input id="firstName" size=10 name="firstName"></td></tr>
            <tr><td class = "field"><label for="lastName">Last Name:</label></td><td><input id="lastName" size=15 name="lastName"></td></tr>
            <tr><td class = "field"><label for="address1">Address 1:</label></td><td><input id="address1" size=25 name="address1"></td></tr>
            <tr><td class = "field"><label for="address2">Address 2:</label></td><td><input id="address2" size=25 name="address2"></td></tr>
            <tr><td class = "field"><label for="city">City:</label></td><td><input id="city" size=20 name="city"></td></tr>
            <tr><td class = "field"><label for="province">Province:</label></td><td><input id="province" size=20 name="province"></td></tr>
            <tr><td class = "field"><label for="postalCode">Postal Code:</label></td><td><input id="postalCode" size=7 name="postalCode"></td></tr>
        </table>
    </form>
```

Text File example (english.txt)

```
First Name:,Last Name:,Address 1:,Address 2:,City:,Province:,Postal Code:
```

Javascript

```
function init(){
var language = document.getElementsByTagName("a");

for (var i = 0, i < language.length; i++){
    language[i].onclick = processRequest;
}
}

function processRequest(e) {
evt = e || window.event;
target = evt.target || evt.srcElement;
request.onreadystatechange = displayData;
request.open('GET', target.id+".txt", true);
request.send(null);
}

function displayData() {
if (request.readyState == 4 && request.status == 200)
    var fields = request.responseText.split(",");
    var labels = document.getElementsByTagName("label");

    for (var i = 0, i < labels.length; i++){
        labels[i].innerText = fields[i];
    }
}


window.onload = init();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You hadn't created ajax request. Remember to put javascript at the end of page and change it to

```
var request;
function init() {
    var language = document.getElementsByTagName("a");
    for (var i = 0; i < language.length; i++) {
        language[i].onclick = processRequest;
    }
}

function processRequest(e) {
    evt = e || window.event;
    target = evt.target || evt.srcElement;
    request = new XMLHttpRequest();
    request.onreadystatechange = displayData;
    request.open('GET', target.id + ".txt", true);
    request.send(null);
}

function displayData() {
    if (request.readyState == 4 && request.status == 200) {
        var fields = request.responseText.split(",");
        var labels = document.getElementsByTagName("label");
        for (var i = 0; i < labels.length; i++) {
            labels[i].innerText = fields[i];
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: the code i edited work fine, but i got some error while post it here, now you can try it

Comment: What was the solution? Here, the `request` variable is global. Were you not passing the `request` variable before? Was the problem the location of the javascript in the document?

Comment: request is a global variable. In this code, **processRequest** function was called before **displayData** function. In otherway, **displayData** function is called inside **processRequest** function and after ajax request created
**request = new XMLHttpRequest();
    request.onreadystatechange = displayData;** @showdev

Comment: Yes, +1 I agree. Those seem very similar to the changes I suggested. I'm just wondering what specifically solved the OP's problem.

Answer (score 1):

There is another error: `Can't find variable: request`.

The "request" variable is not defined.

```
function processRequest(e) {
    evt = e || window.event;
    target = evt.target || evt.srcElement;
    var request = new XMLHttpRequest();             <<-- added this
    request.onreadystatechange = displayData(request);
    request.open('GET', target.id+".txt", true);
    request.send(null);
}
```

Also, you may want to restructure the `displayData()` function to accept a passed `request` variable and to continue conditionally based on the request state/status. Otherwise, `fields` is not defined : `'undefined' is not an object (evaluating 'fields[i]')`.

```
function displayData(request) {
    if (request.readyState == 4 && request.status == 200) {
        var fields = request.responseText.split(",");
        var labels = document.getElementsByTagName("label");

        for (var i = 0; i < labels.length; i++) {
            labels[i].innerText = fields[i];
        }
    }
}
```

### Edit:

Also, if your javascript is in the `<head>` section of your page, change your `init` function call to: `window.onload = init;` (without the parenthesis). Otherwise, the `init` function will be executed immediately, before the document is loaded.

Comment: Unfortunately it still doesn't work even with those changes. The alerts still work everywhere too. Could it be my window onload or how I set up all my functions? I really have no idea anymore :(

Comment: I suggest that you check your browser's error console. It helps to track down javascript errors. Let me know what you see there.

Comment: There are absolutely no errors at all showing in Firefox. Can it be I'm not calling my text files correctly? I saved them all with the same ID I have in the form so I can just add .txt to my javascript..

Answer (score 0):

if the code you posted above is exactly the code you used, check your for loop and correct the argument

```
for (var i = 0, i < labels.length; i++)
```

Comment: +1 Agreed. Use a semi-colon instead of the comma. `SyntaxError: Unexpected token '<'`

Comment: That helped a bit but not quite. My alert now showed but the form still doesnt change language.

Comment: My alerts work no matter where I place them, beginning or end. So I guess that rules out a syntax error....